# Showing last viewd page after closing application

Tags: android, android-intent

am new in android and troubled with  some problem in my first application.I installed application on phone but after closing the application(using the close button of phone) again when i re open the application , the last opened page on the previous launch shown again .Am confused ..
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot close any application in android it just goes to background

you can try this it will work

write `finish();` after your write `startActivity(intentName);` in your code

and dont press the close button press the back button to exit

Comment: but happens when we press the close button ?finish(); will also work on this case?

Comment: no finish wont work in that case
pressing home button takes your application to background
so the last activity would be brought to front since it is in background

Comment: how to avoid this? when press the home button how i can start a new activity?

Answer (score 3):

when you have created the activity as shown below

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
            // Your stuffs
     startActivity(new Intent(present_activity.this, Next_Acitivity.class));
     finish();
}
```

when your going old activity to new activity called this `finish()` to finish the old activity.

When you click on back button , activity should get finished or closed using `onKeyDown` methods.

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
finish();
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```